# C Queue questions (Exercise)

Tags: c, queue

I just started my first lesson in queues for C, and I was given an exercise to create a queue, adding elements and deleting elements into the queue. However, I am having trouble with checking whether the queue is full or empty.

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> typedef struct FloatQueue
> {
>   float data[100];
>   int rear;
>   int size;
>   int front;
> } FloatQueue;
>
> typedef enum {false, true} bool;
>
> void initQ (FloatQueue * pq);
> bool isFullQ (FloatQueue * pq);
> bool isEmptyQ (FloatQueue * pq);
> void addQ(FloatQueue * pq, float x);
> float deleteQ (   FloatQueue * pq);
> int sizeQ (FloatQueue * pq);
>
>
> void initQ (FloatQueue * pq)
> {
>   pq->size = 0;
>   pq->front = pq->rear = 0;
> }
>
> void main ()
> {
>   FloatQueue q1;
>   initQ (&q1);
>
>   addQ (&q1, 99.9);
>
>   addQ (&q1, 888);
>
>   while (!isEmptyQ(&q1))
>   {
>       printf("%f", deleteQ (&q1));
>   }
>
> }
>
> int sizeQ (FloatQueue * pq)
> {
>   return pq->size;
> }
>
> bool isFullQ (FloatQueue * pq)
> {
>   return true;
> }
>
> bool isEmptyQ (FloatQueue * pq)
> {
>
>   return false;
> }
>
> void addQ ( FloatQueue * pq, float x)
> {
>   (pq->rear) ++;
>   (pq->data[pq->rear]) = x;
>   (pq->size) ++;
>
> }
>
> float deleteQ ( FloatQueue * pq )
> {
>   (pq->front)++;
>   return;
> }
> ```

Comment: Just check if size == 0 (empty) or size == 100 (full)

Comment: What did you try already to solve your question?

Comment: I suggest you go through the code carefully again, reviewing what each of your functions is supposed to do. What was the reason you added a size variable to the queue structure? Is that not supposed to reflect the size of the queue any time? In that case, isn't your "delete queue" (which actually is de-queue) supposed to decrement size? Also think about what you want to return from the de-queue API.

Comment: A good unit test would be to repeat { addQ(pq, 1.0); deleteQ(pq); } 1000 times. I'd expect a segfault with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

The queue is full if `size == 100` and empty if `size == 0`. Why is it difficult to check for that?

However, as it is implemented now, it holds that `size == 0` if and only if `front == rear`. That means, you *could* remove the `size` from the `FloatQueue` completely and instead check if `front - rear == 0` resp. 100.

*BUT:* You have to think about one thing: what happens if the rear end exceeds the size? Then you surely have to rearrange something. I leave it to you to find a good solution, which could might mean making use of `size` again after all (Hint: you don't necessarily have to move data around in the array).

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isFullQ (FloatQueue * pq)
{
  if(pq->size==100) 
  return true;
}

bool isEmptyQ (FloatQueue * pq)
{
  if(pq->front==pq->rear)
  return false;
}
```